# How to implement Observable.Publish for an array of observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm looking to implement the following function:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Publish<TSource, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TSource>[] sources,
    Func<IObservable<TSource>[], IObservable<TResult>> selector)
{
  // how?
}
```

The behaviour should be identical to the existing

```
IObservable<TResult> Publish<TSource, TResult>(
    IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<IObservable<TSource>, Iobservable<TResult>> selector)
```

With the only difference of course being source (and the parameter of selector) being an array of observables. Basically, "given an array of observables, produce a result observable while sharing one single subscription to each of the array's observables".

Can this be done in any clever way?

My only ideas so far were implementing this via expression trees that chain the single-observable `.Publish()` calls - which isn't feasible for performance reasons.

Or going for something like this. But this seems messy, and I find it quite hard to reason about correctness

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Publish<TSource, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TSource>[] sources,
    Func<IObservable<TSource>[], IObservable<TResult>> selector)
{
  return Observable.Create<TResult>(observer => 
  {
    var published = sources.Select(x => x.Publish()).ToArray();
    var result = new CompositeDisposable();
    result.Add(selector(published).Subscribe(observer));
    foreach(var p in published)
      result.Add(p.Connect());
    return result;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution now, but would be more than happy to hear about better ideas!

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Publish<TSource, TResult>(this IReadOnlyList<IObservable<TSource>> sources, Func<IReadOnlyList<IObservable<TSource>>, IObservable<TResult>> selector)
{
  IObservable<TResult> Generator(ImmutableArray<IObservable<TSource>> published)
  {
    return published.Length == sources.Count
      ? selector(published)
      : sources[published.Length].Publish(x => Generator(published.Add(x)));
  }

  return Generator(ImmutableArray<IObservable<TSource>>.Empty);
}
```

---

The question of why this is useful came up. Just for clarity, I'm attaching one of the things I intend to do with this. The following function works the same as the existing CombineLatest(), but has integrated throttling: The first combination of items is emitted immediately, everything thereafter is debounced, which can be helpful if the invocation of the result selector is expensive.

```
public static IObservable<TResult> CombineLatest<TSource, TResult>(this IReadOnlyList<IObservable<TSource>> sources, Func<IList<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector, TimeSpan timeSpan, IScheduler? scheduler = null)
{
  scheduler ??= Scheduler.Default;
  return sources.Publish<TSource, TResult>(publishedSources => publishedSources
    .CombineLatest(_ => Unit.Default)
    .Publish(x => x.Take(1).Merge(x.Skip(1).Sample(timeSpan, scheduler))
    .Publish(signal => publishedSources
      .Select(source => signal.WithLatestFrom(source, (_,value) => value))
      .Zip()
      .Select(resultSelector)));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems to me that the `selector` that you're using is wrong.

Here is the implementation with your current `selector`:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Publish<TSource, TResult>(
        this IObservable<TSource>[] sources,
        Func<IObservable<TSource>[], IObservable<TResult>> selector)
    => selector(sources);
```

It's trivial. It's also a bit tautological. Your `selector` is sort of the thing you're trying to create.

The only sensible selector is `Func<IObservable<TSource>, IObservable<TResult>> selector`.

It can it be done this way:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Publish<TSource, TResult>(
        this IObservable<TSource>[] sources,
        Func<IObservable<TSource>, IObservable<TResult>> selector)
    => sources.Select(x => x.Publish(selector)).Merge();
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure what you mean by "the selector is wrong" though? (Not a very useful example, but imagine e.g. some_observables.Publish(p => p.CombineLatest().Take(1).Select(y => ...some transformation for the first batch...).Merge(p.Select(y => y.Skip(1)).Merge()))

Comment: @Bogey - I can't make heads nor tails of what your `some_observables` is doing. I've updated the answer with an explanation of why I think your `selector` is wrong.

Comment: Your answer is wrong unfortunately, it would potentially lead to multiple subscriptions to a given observable within sources .. imagine a contrieved example like selector = x => x[0].First().Merge(x[0].Skip(1)). This would lead to 2 different subscription to the first obseravble within sources

Comment: I have come up with a bit of an ugly solution in the meantime by the way, I'll post this as an answer here including an example for a use case of this function, maybe that makes it a little more clear. Still very happy to hear about better ideas!

Comment: @Bogey - Yes, I think you're right. In hind sight this is almost a no-op operator. I'll need to rethink.